# Can I degas to increase pH in a stuck fermentation?

Tags: stuck-fermentation, acidity, degassing

I have an *oak leaf and burdock* wine that has gotten stuck at a SG of 1.024. The pH reads 2.76, so I suspect that the high acidity has caused it to get stuck.

I understand that dissolved CO<sub>2</sub> can cause a wine to be too acidic, so I'm wondering if I might be able to restart the fermentation by degassing the wine at this point, thus increasing the pH?

I do however recall reading somewhere that degassing a wine before the end of fermentation is pointless as the CO<sub>2</sub> will recover in a matter of minutes. Can anyone advise? I don't want to go ahead and try it if it would only risk oxidising the wine with no benefit. The backup plan is to add precipitated chalk.

Comment: I'm not much of a wine maker but I would go ahead with the chalk, or pickling lime.  pH of 2.76 seems very very low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally it should be around ~3.2-3.5, so I would consider increasing the PH first as a start. Just degassing won't work I think. Aside from increasing the PH, you may need to add-in additional yeast nutrients, but I suggest doing it step-by-step.